# SQL 'Group By' and Count

Tags: sql

```
------------------
| ID | Other |
------------------
| 1  | 1 |
------------------
| 1  | 2 |
------------------
| 1  | 3 |
------------------
| 2  | 1 |
------------------
| 2  | 2 |
------------------
| 2  | 3 |
------------------
```

How can I write a query which groups by 'ID' and then UNIONS the 'Other' (so that I can determine which 'ID's have the same 'Other' field)?
I also want to be able to keep track of how many each 'Other's each of the 'ID's have. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: not sure I understand the question. Can you share the result you'd expect for this input?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that with the term : UNIONS you really mean CONCATENATING others values, if so i depends on the database server you have, for example MySQL have GROUP_CONCAT :

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Other) FROM table GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Actually, I think he wants `SELECT Other, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) FROM table GROUP BY Other`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(Other)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```